# Marketing Cloud Content Blocks Custom Description

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, custom, content-builder

Is it possible to change the sample text "Lorem ipsum..." in an empty content block in Marketing Cloud Content Builder?
I would like to exchange the sample text with a description on how to use the content block.

Comment: It is not possible, at least from the SFMC UI. Your best bet is to contact your account manager and ask to change the default value from the backend.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking into! If your requirement is as below,
[image]

- Create a new template with the below HTML code.
- update the respective **data-label** with your desired description of the content block to be placed.
- You can add additional tr as much as content blocks you need. [keep in mind that more than 8 blocks, might clip in Gmail!]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
   <head>
      <title>Test template</title>
      <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
      <meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection" />
      <meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport" />
      <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
      <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting" />

   </head>
   <body bgcolor="#f2f0f2" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; -ms-text-size-adjust: none; min-width: 100%;" yahoo="fix">
      <custom name="opencounter" type="tracking" />
     <custom name="usermatch" type="tracking" />
      <table align="center" bgcolor="#f2f0f2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="email-container">
         <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">
               <table align="center" bgcolor="#f2f0f2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" style="max-width: 100%;" width="640">
                  <tr>
                     <td align="center" class="container" valign="top">
                        <table align="center" bgcolor="#f2f0f2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                           <tr>
                              <td align="center" valign="top">
                                 <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                       <td align="right" valign="top" bgcolor="#f2f0f2">
                                          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                             <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                   <td align="right" valign="top">
                                                      <div data-type="slot" data-key="preheader" data-label="Annika_test"></div>
                                                   </td>
                                                </tr>
                                             </tbody>
                                          </table>
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td align="center" valign="top">
                                          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                             <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                   <td align="center" valign="top">
                                                      <div data-type="slot" data-key="logo_header" data-label="Logo_header"></div>
                                                   </td>
                                                </tr>
                                             </tbody>
                                          </table>
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td align="center" valign="top">
                                          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                             <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                   <td align="center" valign="top">
                                                      <div data-type="slot" data-key="block_01" data-label="Block_01"></div>
                                                   </td>
                                                </tr>
                                             </tbody>
                                          </table>
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td align="center" valign="top">
                                          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                             <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                   <td align="center" valign="top">
                                                      <div data-type="slot" data-key="block_02" data-label="Block_02"></div>
                                                   </td>
                                                </tr>
                                             </tbody>
                                          </table>
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                       <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#f2f0f2">
                                          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                             <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                   <td align="center" valign="top">
                                                      <div data-type="slot" data-key="footer_text" data-label="Footer_text"></div>
                                                   </td>
                                                </tr>
                                             </tbody>
                                          </table>
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </table>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                        </table>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```